# Browser reloaded before server with grunt-express-server and grunt-contrib-watch

Tags: express, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) together with [grunt-express-server](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server) to reload my express server and the browser page whenever I made changes to the javascript files. The problem I am having is that the page reloads before the server is ready, so I get a "can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000."

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';
    grunt.initConfig({
        express: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    script: 'gui-resources/scripts/js/server.js'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            express: {
                files: ['gui-resources/scripts/js/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['express:dev'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Load all grunt tasks declared in package.json
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['express:dev', 'watch'])
};
```

In my server.js file I start the server with:

```
    var port = 3000;
    app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Listening on port %d', port);
    });
```

I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502339/grunt-express-server-with-contrib-watch), but the solution proposed there doesn't apply on my case, since I am logging some output when the server is started, but the race condition appears anyway.

**Update:**
If I remove 'spawn: false' from watch:express config, everything works but express logs an error when started:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:878:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1016:14)
at listen (net.js:1038:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1104:5)
at Function.app.listen (/Users/pat/projects/sourcefabric/plugin-liveblog-embed-server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:533:24)
at /Users/pat/projects/sourcefabric/plugin-liveblog-embed-server/gui-resources/scripts/js/server.js:86:13
at Object.context.execCb (/Users/pat/projects/sourcefabric/plugin-liveblog-embed-server/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1890:33)
at Object.Module.check (/Users/pat/projects/sourcefabric/plugin-liveblog-embed-server/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1106:51)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pat/projects/sourcefabric/plugin-liveblog-embed-server/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1353:34)
at /Users/pat/projects/sourcefabric/plugin-liveblog-embed-server/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:372:23
```

Strange enough, in spite of the error the server and the page reload correctly.

Here is my [code](https://github.com/patriciagarcia/plugin-liveblog-embed-server/tree/livereload) (the real Gruntfile is bigger, but I removed the parts not related to watch or express to make the question more readable).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use the [`debounceDelay` option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsdebouncedelay) with `livereload` to wait a bit longer until your server is ready:

```
watch: {
    express: {
        files: ['gui-resources/scripts/js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['express:dev'],
        options: {
            livereload: true,
            spawn: false,
            debounceDelay: 1000 // in milliseconds
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That didn't solve the problem, though, even if I introduce a very big delay.

Comment: Interesting. So then it isn't an issue with restarting the browser after the server?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I'll try to elaborate a little bit more in my answer. Actually, the issue is still that the browser is restarting before the server. I can see the browser reloading and giving an error before "Listening on port 3000" is shown in the console. debounceDelay doesn't seem to change that, even using a delay of 5000 or even 10000 ms.

Comment: I edited the question to add a link to the whole code in Github, in case it helps to find the problem.

Comment: Hmm... well, the `EADDRINUSE` error occurs when the port that your server wants to listen on is already in use. Obviously there are other issues than just timing here. Not sure what to do about that. :(

Comment: Yep, EADDRINUSE only happens when I remove 'spawn: false' (which according to grunt-express-server documentation is needed for the server to reload), so it may be that the problem in this case is that the server is not yet completely down before the re-start happens? Anyway, even with the error the server seems to work, so maybe I should just use it like this. Thanks for the help anyway!